# Fringing effect of electric current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current

We know the what is the fringing effect of electric field in capacitor, of magnetic field in some in some solenoid or magnetic field in through joint of some metal. But is there is something similar fringing effect for electric current. If yes then please explain it.

Comment: Yes, there is, for conductors with inhomogeneous conductivity.

Comment: Can you tell me it in bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fringing in cases of electric fields and magnetic fields are mandated by the laws of electromagnetism. For electric current, there is no such law which would be violated in case fringing does not happen. It must be made clear that current in itself is not a 'field'. Therefore, even if fringing does happen, it is not 'similar' to the case of the capacitor or the inductor.

There cannot be measurable fringing of electric current while moving through metallic wires as the conductivity of the metal is a few million times that of any surrounding material. It may be measurable if suppose we dip the wire in a good electrolyte as the electrons have another path(s) of low resistance outside the boundary of the wire.